# how to display an image in a div that is kept on next page loading using jquery?

Tags: jquery

i got a template displaying an image , something like:

```
<div id='menu_photo'>
      <div id='menu_photo_container'>
        <img id='click_menu_photo' src='/../../wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Image_Slider1.jpg'/>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Depending on which click on menu , i'd like to display a different image using jquery , something like

```
jQuery(function ($) {

      $('.menu-item').on({
      'click': function(){      
          $('#click_menu_photo').attr('src','/../../wp-content/uploads/2013/07/IMG_0750-rec22-150x150.jpg');
       });
});
```

As soon as i click it does change the picture in the code .
The problem i have is then the page get reloaded and the image is back as defined in the template again (not the one from the last click) .
How can i solve this ?

Comment: is the page expected to reload? (i.e. do you want it to reload or not?)

Comment: i want it to reload yes. this is a navigation menu

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `menu-item` is but probably you need to [prevent the default behavior](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) of the event. Something like this should do the trick

```
$('.menu-item').on({
'click': function(e){      
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent element default behavior on click
    $('#click_menu_photo').attr('src','/../../wp-content/uploads/2013/07/IMG_0750-rec22-150x150.jpg');
});
```

Comment: what if i want the $('#click_menu_photo').attr('src') to be default prevented ( and not the menu-item on click event )?

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
$('#click_menu_photo').on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).attr('src','http://www.zwani.com/graphics/hello/images/10.gif');  
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qQhHx/

I hope it helps.

Comment: what if i want the $('#click_menu_photo').attr('src') to be default prevented ( and not the menu-item on click event )?